# Update Kaltura Media entry plays

Tags: kaltura

I'm trying to update field "plays" of a media Entry but while the code runs without any problems/exceptions the value of the entry stays the same.

The code i'm using is below :

```
try {
    String ks = client.getSessionService().start(ADMIN_SECRET, "admin",
            KalturaSessionType.ADMIN, PARTNER_ID, 86400, "disableentitlement");
    client.setKs(ks);
    client.setSessionId(ks);

    // Get Media Entry
    KalturaMediaEntry getMediaEntry = client.getMediaService().get(entry_id);
    // Get plays of Media Entry
    int plays = getMediaEntry.plays;

    int updatedPlays = plays + 1;

    // Create updated Media Entry with plays+1
    KalturaMediaEntry updatedMediaEntry = new KalturaMediaEntry();
    updatedMediaEntry.plays = updatedPlays;

    // Update
    client.getMediaService().update(entry_id, updatedMediaEntry);

 } catch (KalturaApiException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.i(TAG, "Update Num of plays error: " + e.getMessage() );
}
```

Anyone can help me with this? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`KalturaMediaEntry.plays` is not updatable using the API, this is a read-only field.
See https://github.com/kaltura/server/blob/Kajam-11.18.0/api_v3/lib/types/entry/KalturaPlayableEntry.php#L12

The API should actually be throwing an error when trying to update this field.

I assume that you are using a self hosted version of Kaltura, in that case it is possible to update plays using a direct DB script.

You can use https://github.com/kaltura/server/blob/Kajam-11.18.0/alpha/scripts/utils/updateEntryInSphinx.php as an example.
Located at `/opt/kaltura/app/alpha/scripts/utils/updateEntryInSphinx.php`

Before `$sphinx->saveToSphinx($entry, false, true);` add

```
$entry->setPlays($entry->getPlays() + 1);
$entry->save();
```

Execute with `php /opt/kaltura/app/alpha/scripts/utils/updateEntryInSphinx.php ENTRY_ID execute`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, Roman. I'm not using a self hosted version of kaltura. Everything is hosted on kaltura.com (mediaSpace site and the kmc console ). Users create a mediaspace account and i'm using [link](https://knowledge.kaltura.com/faq/how-retrieve-download-or-streaming-url-using-api-calls) to build a url for each entry and stream it. That's why I initially thought that I wouldn't have to update "plays" but then I noticed their value didn't change.

Comment: If you are not using the Kaltura player, you can send statistics manually, see how the player does it on https://github.com/kaltura/mwEmbed/blob/master/modules/KalturaSupport/resources/mw.KAnalytics.js#L186